# Android: Why is my soft keyboard hiding after these key events?

Tags: android

I have a WebView in my Android Application that is giving me a problem. At first was not handling the keyDown event correctly for the arrow keys, and I had to catch the keyDown and use Javascript like this to process them correctly:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.v(TAG, "KeyCode: " + keyCode + "    KeyEvent: " + event);
    switch(keyCode) {
    case 19: /* Up */
        this.loadUrl("javascript:editor.setCursor(editor.getCursor().line - 1, editor.getCursor().ch);");
    case 20: /* Down */
        this.loadUrl("javascript:editor.setCursor(editor.getCursor().line + 1, editor.getCursor().ch);");
    case 21: /* Left */
        this.loadUrl("javascript:editor.setCursor(editor.getCursor().line, editor.getCursor().ch - 1);");
    case 22: /* Right */
        this.loadUrl("javascript:editor.setCursor(editor.getCursor().line, editor.getCursor().ch + 1);");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But now I am getting an issue that every time I use one of the arrow keys the soft keyboard is hiding.

I found one other question here on Stackoverflow that seems to be the exact same issue, but nobody answered him:

[Prevent Buttons From Hiding Soft Keyboard On Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016430/prevent-buttons-from-hiding-soft-keyboard-on-android)

Is there some way I can prevent the softkeyboard from hiding on me?

Comment: Could you try using return false instead of return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); ?

Comment: @rOim I tried return false but it still closed the keyboard.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522727/android-soft-keyboard-will-hide-for-no-reason) is the work around and the reason for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because loadUrl/loadData/loadDataWithBaseUrl internally hides soft keyboeard. You should not send javascript events until user has typed everything he wants. If it is appropriate, handle events via javascript.