# Android webview losing focus

Tags: android, android-webview

Situation: I have a webview with an html input field in it for typing a location, there is a webview sitting underneath it to display suggestions. There is a keyup handler and an onchange handler on that input field. on keyup there is a message sent out to call an api to populate the suggestion webview.

Problem: After typing one character, the input field loses focus. On android 2.3 the keyboard stays up but continued typing does nothing. on android 4.1 the onchange handler gets triggered (as though the user had hit enter to submit what they had typed instead of seleting a suggestion) and the keyboard and webviews get taken away.

Things I have considered: An external loadURL call could cause this (like 'javascript: var...'), calling 'requestFocus' or 'bringToFront' on some other view could also cause this. Setting a event handler on a view tree listener might help clear things up.

Unfortunately, as far as I have been able to tell, no url change is happening, no other views seem to be requesting focus or are being brought to the front. Putting a handler on the view tree listener did not help--it was triggered after the input field lost focus.

I'm out of ideas to try to find the cause of this focus change.

What can I do to investigate this further and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is loadUrl being called at all (after the first time)?  It turns out that loadUrl automatically closes the keyboard.  If you *are* using loadUrl, I found a workaround!  Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776064/513038.