# How to prevent Button press from closing soft keyboard

Tags: android, wordpress, button, keyboard, android-webview

I have implemented a note-taking UI where a `WebView` accepts user input and below it is a row of buttons that toggle formatting inside of the `WebView`. The buttons sit on the bottom of the layout, so when the soft-keyboard pops up when the `WebView` has focus the buttons sit just above the keyboard.

This is working great, but my problem is that whenever one of the buttons is pressed the soft-keyboard closes.  **I want to leave the soft-keyboard as it is whenever a button is pressed.** So if it is closed, a button press won't open it, and if it is open then a button press won't close it.

I found the Wordpress Android source code, and the layout is extremely similar and it has the exact button-keyboard interaction I want.

The relevant sources on GitHub are here [Activity Code](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/src/org/wordpress/android/ui/posts/EditPostActivity.java#L366) and here [Layout XML](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/res/layout/edit.xml)

I can't figure out how they do it though. They don't call the [`InputMethodManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), which I am trying to avoid if possible since it can cause jumpy behavior where the keyboard has to re-open itself whenever a button is pressed. The one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016430/prevent-buttons-from-hiding-soft-keyboard-on-android) I found had answers that essentially said to do exactly that, or create a useless view to get the focus to prevent the keyboard from closing. Neither seem very efficient.

Comment: I believe you need to use `setFocusable(false)` on the buttons. This way the focus will stay on the WebView.

Comment: @Randy No luck. I have also tried manually switching to focus to the `WebView` when the buttons are clicked, same result.