# Prevent Softkeyboard from hiding when DialogFragment opens in Android

Tags: android

In my app, I have list of chat messages. Each message on click shows popup context dialog menu. My problem is that, when user clicks the input window, Soft-keyboard is opened, then he clicks on of the messages. When DialogFragment is opened it closes Soft-keyboard.

How I can prevent closing Soft-keyboard on dialog opening just like Hangouts does in screenshot?

I have these settings in Manifest for this activity:

```
          android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

[image]

Comment: try first solution from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016430/prevent-buttons-from-hiding-soft-keyboard-on-android

Comment: didn't help, Softkeyboard still hides when popup opens